# Line breaks in text incorrect in mobile app

Tags: bug, android-app

The initial version of [this answer](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/1459/283) contains code (formatted manually, not with the code format feature) that looks like this on my laptop (OS X running Chrome):

[image: Screenshot from laptop]

On my Android (7.1.1) phone (Sony Xperia Z5 Compact) running the Stack Exchange app (1.0.95), I see:

[image: Screenshot from Android phone]

The difference is significant, as we are discussing coding style.

Since I took the screenshots, someone has submitted an edit to the answer to use the code formatting feature, so you will need to look at the original version.

Comment: Same behavior for [tag:ios-app]